# Laravel 5.2 Bcrypt broken therefore Auth broken

Tags: php, laravel, bcrypt

So I dont know whats going on but heres some fun for you. If I do this

```
return bcrypt('hello');
exit();
```

and run it 3 times this is what I get back:

1st : `$2y$10$T11IfKkHIAIXi0SRhjMXKeSQQtze8zBVZnWdlRXfsSdcCXKIq/n7W`

2nd: `$2y$10$DpKVtgbF4OVa3jm.wdG5..jb9AvXsuo2EfqnjuzmsEVCmcOVr5nKq`

3rd: `$2y$10$0.ziFneJu0wrS2b3rHA6kucnGBkS2MRtgfp0gtEb/7ZOCV8dG3Mmq`

I'm stumped. Worked in laravel 5.1 - Don't know if it's my fault or not. and sorry. Anyone else having this issue? Is there a fix for it?

Doesn't matter much if I get a answer, 5.2 is <strike>shite</strike> not very good and I'm moving back to laravel 5.1 since A) its more stable and B) It was developed before Taylor Otwell let Gibbons in on the project. Just though I'd ask incase someone came across this and fixed it for other peeps.

Comment: What exactly is your question? This is how a good password hashing system works its not just doing a simple `md5` or something like that this is the same way passwords are calculated in Linux you can still Auth fine with them but it depends on what your trying to do.

Comment: Look at the `Hash::check` function a simple string comparison isn't going to cut it.

Comment: How did you confirm that bcrypt is broken ? If all three time bcrypt would return same value then would it be secure ?

Comment: Because previously I would only have to hash it to check it (like Mark said with md5). I know laravel has it's own implementation (or php dose) of bcrypt because when trying bcrypt with node I wasn't able to install it (windows you see).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use the [`Hash::check`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/hashing#basic-usage) function

```
Hash::check('hello', '$2y$10$T11IfKkHIAIXi0SRhjMXKeSQQtze8zBVZnWdlRXfsSdcCXKIq/n7W');

=> true

Hash::check('not-hello', '$2y$10$T11IfKkHIAIXi0SRhjMXKeSQQtze8zBVZnWdlRXfsSdcCXKIq/n7W');

=> false

Hash::check('hello', '$2y$10$DpKVtgbF4OVa3jm.wdG5..jb9AvXsuo2EfqnjuzmsEVCmcOVr5nKq');

=> true

Hash::check('hello', '$2y$10$0.ziFneJu0wrS2b3rHA6kucnGBkS2MRtgfp0gtEb/7ZOCV8dG3Mmq');

=> true

Hash::check('hello', '$2y$10$0.ziFneJu0wrS2b3rHA6kucnGFkS2MRtgfp0gtEb/7ZOCV8dG3Mmq');

=> false
```

To explain how this works you might want to check out the Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)

> For example, the shadow password record
>   $2a$10$N9qo8uLOickgx2ZMRZoMyeIjZAgcfl7p92ldGxad68LJZdL17lhWy specifies
>   a cost parameter of 10, indicating 2<sup>10</sup> key expansion rounds. The salt
>   is N9qo8uLOickgx2ZMRZoMye and the resulting hash is
>   IjZAgcfl7p92ldGxad68LJZdL17lhWy. Per standard practice, the user's
>   password itself is not stored.

Also for more reading [Do any security experts recommend bcrypt for password storage?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage)

For even more reading [Storing User Passwords Securely: hashing, salting, and Bcrypt](http://dustwell.com/how-to-handle-passwords-bcrypt.html)